# How to get all commit messages in a repo by one author?

Tags: git

How can I retrieve a list of all commit messages in a git repo for a given commit author?

Comment: `git log --all --author ...`

Comment: Well that was easy. @Biffen please make that an answer so I can accept it. I might add `--format=%B` to get just the messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
git log --all --author <author regex>
```

Easy to work out by reading [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_limiting). Note that it's a regex, so some characters may need escaped.

Comment: I'll copy my comment above here: adding `--format=%B`retrieves just the messages. And @Biffen, you're right, i should have RTFMd before googling/SOing. Too easy to use google as a TOC for the manual :/

Comment: Googling is just fine, but the effort required to ask here and the wait for an answer is why I'm amazed people ask questions like this.

Answer (score 10):

In command line:

```
git log --author=<author name> --pretty=format:"%h - %an :%cn  %s"
```

h - short form of hash

an - author name

cn - committer name

s - message (subject)